# How to replace data in a certain node in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I have an exercise using linked lists for my class. I am fairly new to the language, but I've given it an attempt. The instructions tell us to "iterate through until NodeData is found, then replace the data using the sets."
What are "the sets" in C++? I've looked online and I couldn't find anything. The only thing I can think of is setting the nodes to point somewhere else. For example `head->NULL`. But is this really necessary if I am simply replacing the data? To replace the data I've tried `temp->order = NEWDATA`. Is that the correct implementation? It did not seem to work. Maybe it was an error in a different part of the code.

```
bool OrderLL::Modify(Order * NodeData) {
    OrderNode *temp = head;
    if (temp == NULL) {
        cout << "Empty List";
    }
    else {
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (temp->order == NodeData) {

                //not sure if this is the proper way of deleting data inside a node
                delete anOrder;
               //HOW DO I REPLACE THE DATA IN THIS PART?
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

return false;
}
```

On a side note, I really do not understand why  I continue to recieve downvotes on all my questions. Is it because they're basic C++ questions? They're not so basic to me. I know this website looks down upon "offtopic/chat discussions" but I just don't understand what is wrong with my questions.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the sets". Why not just assign `node->data = newnod->data`. Can't tell more without seeing the structure though.

Comment: Odds are you are supposed to have a "setter" mutator function, but no way to be sure without more context.

Comment: @DeiDei Doesn't that just copy data from a node to a newnode?

Comment: @Jaden Well, it would copy `data` from `newnode` to `node`. Isn't that what you want (e.g. replace the old data with the new data)?

Comment: @DeiDei Do I have to create a new node (to copy from) in order to replace data in a single node? I cannot just simply delete the old data, then insert new data?

Comment: C++ from what I see on here tends to get more down votes.  Especially homework questions.  Now I wouldn't see it as a negative thing.  It probably just means it isn't inherently clear what you are asking.   I didn't down vote you, but to be honest the only thing I understood clearly was your well-written last paragraph.  Best of luck to you mate, good on you to keep trying.  Don't let it get you down.

Comment: Try to make the question clearer. What is the exact assignment, what are you given, and what do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned "replace" in your question, so just taking a guess but might be you are expected to replace the node itself and not just the data. In which case, it will be something like this

```
if(curr_node->data == to_replace_data){
  curr_node->next = new_node;
  new_node->next = curr_node->next->next;
  free( curr_node->next); //or return curr_node->next depending on what
                      // you are trying to do.
}
```